# Kill EXEL.EXE process while using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: kill-process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Killing an interop Application process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321881/killing-an-interop-application-process)

I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in order to get data from excel. Even though i clear the COM objects it still leaves some instances of EXEL.EXE in the background.Check my code below.

```
finally
        {
            if (cells != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(cells);
            if (range != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(range);
            if (sheets != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(sheets);
            if (workSheet != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(workSheet);
            if (excelWorkBook != null)
            {
                excelWorkBook.Close(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelWorkBook);
            }
            if (excelWorkbooks != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelWorkbooks);

            if (excel != null)
            {
                excel.Quit();
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excel);
            }
            cells = null;
            range = null;
            sheets = null;
            workSheet = null;
            excelWorkBook = null;
            excelWorkbooks = null;
            excel = null;

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        }
```

Please tell me where I have gone wrong.

Comment: A quite extensive cleanup, however 'sheets' is missing in the finalreleasecomobject list?

Comment: Please check the edited code above..Still EXEL.EXE remains in the background.

Comment: If there is edited code in your post, 'sheets' isn't cleaned in it. I've posted an answer as well, because it's easier to use markup in it ;)

Answer (score 1):

The only variable that isn't released is `sheets`, defined as:

```
   sheets = excelWorkBook.Worksheets;
```

Then again, sheets is never used, so it can be left out completely, because worksheet is assigned as:

```
   workSheet = (Worksheet)excelWorkBook.Worksheets["Sheet1"]; //doesn't use sheets, so sheets can be omitted
```

or if sheets is needed, if it's released as well my tests show the excel process closing (before application end, after application end it was always closed successfully)

```
   Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(sheets);
```